# Is there way to check react native app version?

Tags: react-native

Let's say I have uploaded my app version *1.0.0* to app store and play store.

After that I have released new version which is *1.0.1*. So, I wonder how can we notify user that app need to update.

I have searched and read lots of article but all of them are using packages which some are outdated and most are not working. Can someone help me please?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-react-native-in-app-updates is the package that I used.

Answer (score 3):

You can install this lib called [react-native-device-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#getversion), and use it as follow:

```js
import VersionNumber from 'react-native-version-number';

[...]

    render() {
        var versionNumber = `${VersionNumber.appVersion}.${VersionNumber.buildVersion}`;

        return (
            <Text style={ styles.versionText }>App Version: {versionNumber}</Text>
        )
    }
[...]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hi William, am wonder how can we compare local app version with store version.

Comment: There's [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-store-version) module who can help you get the store version of your app (Android & IOS), and also check if it's newer than your local app version. So if you want to just compare, you probably dont need react-native-device-info.

Answer (score 1):

you can check latest version on store and your current version of app by this [react-native-version-check](https://github.com/kimxogus/react-native-version-check) and also must check this I think this help you most [app-upgrade-react-native-sdk](https://github.com/appupgrade-dev/app-upgrade-react-native-sdk).

Comment: thank you Arunabh i will get back to you if i have any doubts. thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches to this case:

1. Detect and compare local version against the most recent version available in the store, based on that create some actions in your app.(With use of for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-store-version)
2. In-app updates, with some library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-react-native-in-app-updates